# Test WPA2-PSK credentials

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, openwrt, wpa2-psk

Is there a way to test if WPA2-PSK credentials are correct without having to restart the wifi interface?

I am using OpenWRT on a router, and I am providing the user with a web front-end to select a nearby network and provide the password, which I then use to enter the router into client mode. However, before I do that, I want to test the credentials are correct. I have tried re-writing the /etc/config/wireless file and using wpa_supplicant (the latter of which doesn't seem to work very well on OpenWRT, but this is probably because I'm a n00b) and both cause the wifi on the router to be restarted, which I need to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Look into Virtual STA interfaces, if you can use an 802.11 chipset that supports it.

VSTAs are kind of like Virtual AP interfaces (VAPs) but for STA mode (a.k.a. station mode, client mode). You might be able to keep a VSTA around and tell wpa_supplicant to use the VSTA interface to test the credentials without resetting the whole radio.

Then again, maybe not, because a radio can't be on two channels at the same time, so if the user picks an SSID whose nearest AP is on a different channel than whatever channel your radio picked when it came up in AP mode, I'm not sure what will happen.

Comment: I hadn't come across VSTAs in my search. I'll definitely give this a try!